# webClient.DownloadString - extracting source code - not all elements are being picked up

Tags: c#, web-scraping, webclient

The following script is supposed to write the source code of the URL to a .txt file:

```
private void buttonFetch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        string itemSelection = comboBoxItem.Text.ToString();
        string s;

        if (itemSelection == "item1")
        {
            s = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=batman+action+figure&_ftrv=1&_sadis=200&_ipg=200&_sop=12&LH_SALE_CURRENCY=0&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_dmd=1&_ftrt=901&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.XBatman+Arkham+Origins+Series+1+&_nkw=Batman+Arkham+Origins+Series+1+&_sacat=0");
        }
        else 
        {
            s = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.othersite.com");
        }

        string fixedString = s.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Alex\Dropbox\Personal Projects\loadSheet.txt", fixedString);

        MessageBox.Show("New items are ready to browse.","", 
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);

    }
}
```

Note: both URLs produce a different Ebay search result.

The element that is not being picked up is `<span class="fee">`

However, when I paste the URL into Chrome and right-click --> View Page Source, I can see this element in the source code.

AFAIK, all of the rest of the elements are being pulled into the text file.

Is there any way to ensure this element will be picked up?

**Note** - I had to customize the search results in order to see that span in the source code. To do this, click View --> then click Customize. Then check Shipping Cost. The span should then appear in the source code when you manually view it through Chrome. However, I cannot get the span to display in the code when I use `webClient.Download`.

Comment: The page never include `<span class="fee">` either you use browser like Chrome or webClient.Download. Its likely another request made after clicking 'apply changes' in 'Customize' dialog which return page with `<span class="fee">` included. So the question actually is how to make that request